# Adding a group to a folder structure "basing" on another existing group's rights

Tags: powershell, permissions, network-share, access-control-list

thanks for reading this wall of text anyways.

My scenario:

i have a mega-folder called Projects. Every subfolder is a different project. So, for example, i have Projects\N123456 - New Coca Cola.

Now, the folder N123456blabla has a set of subfolders, each one (or almost) with specific not inherited permissions from the "mother" N123456blabla folder.

Let's suppose that the base folder N123456's access is allowed to a AD group called "internal_users" with specific permissions. There are then some subfolders

SUB-A
SUB-B
SUB-C
SUB-D
SUB-E
etc.

Those subfolders have other subfolders that have other subfolders and so on but let's keep this "clean" in order to better explain the issue. Each SUB folder has specific permissions: for example, SUB-A has the "internal_users" group in read only and the "project_management" group with r/w rights.

Quite common scenario i would say. Now the question.

Let's suppose that i have to add a new group in the parent project folder N123456 called "external_users". This group has to be added also **in every subfolder** **where the "internal_users" group is already in** (remember, most subfolders don't inherit permissions) and it should have the same permissions of the already existing "internal_users" group has in that specific folder.

In order not to edit every project folder (and subfolders) permissions manually, is there a way to achieve this in a more or less automated way?

In short the script should query the folder N123456 and subfolders to see if the group "internal_users" is applied somewhere. If it is, it should **add** to the "affected" folders the "external_users" group with the same permissions that the existing "internal_users" group has in that specific folder. For example, if N123456 parent has "internal_users" in read only, it should add "external_users" in read only. If SUB-B has "internal_users" in r/w it should add "external_users" in r/w. If SUB-C has no group called "internal_users" in, the folder is simply skipped. And so on.

Do you think it can be done somehow?

For new projects this is a non-issue because i changed my template to create the empty structure with an additional "ghost" empty AD group that i then replace with the correct one via icacls editing the SID, but i cannot do this with old projects, because this time i have to add group/groups and not simply replace existing ones.

Edit: one thing I just thought is to export the folders permissions structure into a .csv, then edit the .csv to add the group(s) I need and import it back. But I have no idea in Excel how to mass duplicate only the rows containing a certain text in one column and changing in the meantime the text of one column (the column with the name of the group) of the duplicated rows.

Edit 2: since it’s not possible to to it with icacls (there’s just no way to simply add a group to the exported icacls txt file even knowing the SID) I thought about this:

1. I export the permissions structure of the folder and subfolders into a .csv file.
2. Now, since I have to go in addition and “luckily” enough the new groups I have to add will have the same permissions of the existing ones, I create a copy of the .csv file.
3. I edit the copy by finding and replacing the “internal_users” group with the “external_users” group.
4. I copypaste ALL the rows of the copy file into the original file.
5. I will then have also a lot of useless duplicate rows but I will use the N++ function to delete them.
6. Now I should have a new .csv file with the original permissions plus the new ones.
7. In theory all that is left to do is import back the .csv into the original folder.
   This leads to a new question: how do I export the folders permissions into a .csv and how can I import the file back after editing, OVERWRITING the actual permissions? I found a lot of ways to export the permissions structure but I didn’t understand well how I can import it back after editing.
   It’s still a lot of manual work, but WAY less than editing every single project folder and subfolders one by one.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just add **external_users** as a member of **internal_users**?

Comment: I can’t because the group that I called external_users is in another (trusted) domain and all the AD groups of my domain are not domain.local. Converting all our AD groups from Globlal to domain.local is out of question, the only chance I have is adding the group(s) directly on the shares.